How to obtain the maximum tolerated I/O time while keeping the CPU usage high
A computer has 6 GB of RAM, of which the operating system takes up 1 GB. The processes all have 512 MB and have the same characteristics. If the goal is a CPU utilization of 98%, what is the maximum I/O wait time tolerated? The answer should be in the form of a percentage.
So, I understand that if the OS takes 1024 MB or RAM, and we have N process that each take up 512 MB of RAM, than the following must hold true:
1024 + 512 * N <= total RAM (6144)
This makes sense are there can't be a total of processes that take up more space than there is, and also because we want to fully use the RAM in order to maximize the CPU usage.
So, we can have a maximum of 10 such processes.
But from this point, how can I derive the maximum I / O time?

Is this a single-core system?  Does the OS support paged virtual memory to make it possible to run more processes than you have RAM for?  (And if so, what's the size of the hot part of working set, and how often does it touch a cold page?)  Is there any requirement to run more than one process?  Does it do any I/O?  I don't think there's enough information to answer this. If we knew the program spent some of its time waiting for I/O, so context-switching to another instance of it could overlap I/O and computation, then we could maybe say something about max I/O latency for a single-core system

@PeterCordes ok, valid questions. So let's see: single-core yes, no support for paged virtual memory, only able to run as long as you have RAM for it (that is why I thought that filling up the RAM as much as possible would be a good ideea, to keep the CPU utilized at maximum capacity). The programs do spend time on I/O, basically that is the question, how much time is the maximum allowed to be spent on I/O while keeping the CPU usage at 98%. The question itself is from an OS book. Thanks!

Oh, I see they're asking about the total time spent waiting for I/O, not the max latency of a single I/O operation.  Is that supposing zero-cost context switching when an I/O begins, to hide the waiting if there's another process that isn't blocked on I/O?  That's not unreasonable with slow I/O devices like rotational HDDs where I/O latency is milliseconds, making context-switch overhead negligible.

So we can have 2% of total time where the CPU is idle because all processes are waiting for I/O.  IDK if there's supposed to be a way to get a number in milliseconds; we'd have to make assumptions about how much I/O parallelism is possible.  (e.g. many real SATA hard drives support a queue depth of typically 32, so the firmware can optimize seek patterns to improve throughput by not necessarily responding in the order requests were made, e.g. doing two nearby reads instead of seeking away and back again.)  And network I/O is very often pipelined.
